# Количество коммитов teamcity

Tags: git, gitlab, teamcity

Можно ли как-то в TeamCity получить количество фиксаций?

Что-то наподобие:

```
git rev-list --count <ветка>
```

Или как выполнить эту команду из TeamCity?

Comment: в тимсити все из коробки работает. на 1 вопрос - да, на второй вопрос -да.

Comment: какая у вас версия ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator 10.

Comment: а зачем количество коммитов? ты хочешь версионность включить ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator Да:)

Comment: с гитом это плохо получается. вообще используй тимсити для этой цели. в `Build number format: ` я прописал `1.0.%build.counter%.%system.build.vcs.number.<VCS_root_name>% `  , который возвращает мне `#1.0.839.20972` , где 839 - номер билда, 20972 - номер ревизия, подробнее вот тут https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-BuildNumberFormat 
С SVN очень хорошо это работает. а с гитом нужно фантазировать. например, версию брать из property

Comment: @SeniorAutomator Если использовать `%system.build.vcs.number.<VCS_root_name>‌​%` - получаешь Hash последнего коммита. Его можно как-то приветси к `int`, ты имеешь ввиду?

Comment: нет. вот именно из за хэша для гита делают по-другому все. все зависит от твоей фантазии как это делать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

количество коммитов можно увидеть только с момента создания конфигурации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

также можно выполнить эту команду. TeamCity предлагает большое количество раннеров. конкретно для этой команды можно выполнить Command Line (CMD\bash)

только комни, что на сервере или агенте, где выполняешь команду, должен быть установлен `Git`  и прописан в `path` 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавил информацию в `Path to Git : C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe`. Пытаюсь запустить, но возникает ошибка: `git не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.`

Comment: надо перезапустить сервис тимисти, чтобы новое окружение подтянулось.

не забудь указать рабочую директорию, иначе скажет, что это не гит репозиторий

Comment: отлично! Спасибо.